# How to use the Angular CLI while in a different directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to serve my app without using `cd`

I tried this:

1. `ng s --servePath=\Projects\front-user\ --optimization --aot`
2. And this:
   `ng s \Projects\front-user\ --optimization --aot`

But I got `Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found` because I  am doing something wrong with the path.

If I do `cd /Projects/front-user/ && ng s --aot --optimization` works perfectly but I would like to know if there is a way to specify the project path.

Thanks!

Comment: you can write a npm script `scripts: {"other" : "cd otherfolder && ng s "}` then you can run `npm run other`

Comment: Its a good way. But is the only way to specify a path with `ng s` ?

Comment: sadly not possible

Answer (score 3):

Not it is not possible because `ng s` search in the current directory for a `angular.json`.

If you run `ng s Projects/front-user/` if will be understood as the project name.

The best solution i can think of is a npm script in you `package.json` like

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd folder && ng serve",
    ...
}
```

Currently there is no parameter for such action, for all parameter [see here](https://angular.io/cli/serve).